# Filename of the excel file upon downloading in Codeigniter

Tags: excel, codeigniter, export

Is it possible to set the filename of a excel to a name from database upon downloading  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not precise, but I guess, probably you want to set the name of an Excell's file possible to download from your page to the name saved in the database.

In CodeIgniter it's possible to use [Download Helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/download_helper.html).

1. First [select](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data) from the DataBase the name you want to show for users and save it to a variable. For example:

> $name.

2. Load Download Helper:

> $this->load->helper('download');

3. Use function force_download() to serve your Excel file for user with your name from DB:

> $data = file_get_contents($excell_file_path); // Read the file's contents
>
> force_download($name, $data);